# Prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=f'(x_0)$, if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and the limit exists and is finite for some point $x_0\in(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I was studying analysis and decided to do some exercises, but there was this one problem on derivatives that i got completely stuck on, and had a really hard time trying to solve it. The problem is the following:

> Assume that $f$ has a finite derivative at each point of the open interval $(a,b)$. Assume also that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)$ exists and is finite for some interior point $x_0$. Prove that the value of this limit is $f'(x_0)$.

I  could not yet finish this problem, but i have some ideas. Here is how it went:

---

We have to show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}=f'(x_0)$, that is for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f'(x)-f'(x_0)|<\varepsilon.$$ Since $f$ has a derivative everywhere in $(a,b)$, then $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, that is, for all $\varepsilon_1>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon_1.$$

---

Now from there, i have no ideia how to continue. I have thought to show that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\implies|f'(x)-f'(x_0)|$, and my reasoning was that if you have a neighborhood around $x_0$, since f is continuous, the derivative would go "smoothly" between the endpoints of the interval, but i fall into the problem of not knowing how to formalize this ideia, if it is correct in the first place (maybe could use something like intermediate value theorem for derivatives, but again, i don't know how that would go).
So, any hints for how to continue the solution (please, *don't* give the whole answer to the problem, i really want to try this on my own)

Comment: Sounds like the Darboux theorem.

Comment: Lower-tech than Darboux's theorem[1] is to apply the Mean Value Theorem to shrinking intervals with $x_0$ as endpoint. <> [1] Not that Darboux's theorem is difficult to state or prove, but it's normally not seen until analysis, while the MVT is a cornerstone of calculus.

Comment: If you are willing to take L'Hopital's Rule for granted, this is a corollary. Just look at the definition of $f'(x_0)$, and see that L'Hopital's Rule applies to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a slightly more general statement of the theorem.

> **Theorem.**
>
> Suppose $x_0\in (a,b)$ and  $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb{R}$ a function which is continuous at $x_0$, differentiable on $I\setminus\{x_0\}$ and such that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f’(x_0)$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$. Then, $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and we have the equality $f’(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f’(x_0)$.

So, the point is that we don’t need to assume differentiability at $x_0$. We merely need to assume continuity at $x_0$, then we can prove differentiability at $x_0$ and the equality.

For the proof, we have that for any $h\neq 0$, we can use the mean-value theorem to find some $\xi_h$ strictly between $x_0$ and $x_0+h$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}&=f’(\xi_h).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Keep in mind that the only reason we were able to use the MVT on the interval $[x_0,x_0+h]$ (or $[x_0+h,x_0]$ if $h<0$) is because we already know $f$ is continuous at $x_0$; without this, the proof would fail. With this in mind, we simply note that since $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f’(x)$ **exists**, we can say that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f’(\xi_h)$ exists as well and equals $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f’(x)$. Thus, by taking the limit $h\to 0$ on both sides of $(*)$, we get that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and
\begin{align}
f’(x_0)&=\lim_{x\to x_0}f’(x).
\end{align}
This completes the proof. I leave it to you to transcribe this into $\epsilon$-$\delta$ for practice if you haven’t already proved the theorems I’m facts along the way. If really need be, I’ll update with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ version.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $l=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f'(x)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be
arbitrary. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $\left|f'(x)-l\right|<\varepsilon$
whenever $x\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)\setminus\{x_{0}\}$. For
any $x$ satisfying $x_{0}<x<x_{0}+\delta$, there exists $\xi_{x}\in(x_{0},x)$
satisfying $f(x)-f(x_{0})=f'(\xi_{x})(x-x_{0})$ (Mean-Value Theorem).
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}-l\right|\\
 & = & \left|f'(\xi_{x})-l\right|\\
 & < & \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
because $\xi_{x}\in(x_{0},x_{0}+\delta)$. Observe that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=f'(x_{0})$,
so letting $x\rightarrow x_{0}+$ yields $|f'(x_{0})-l|\leq\varepsilon$.
Therefore $f'(x_{0})=l$ because $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary.